# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set int field it.besmart.models.Park.idPark to [Ljava.lang.Object;

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

i'm dwelling with this problem.
I have 3 classes

User and Park have a ManyToMany relation, and Piano and Park have a ManyToOne relation.

In the models, the interesting parts are
User.java

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name="users_parcheggio", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="user_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name="park_id") })
    private Set<Park> parks = new HashSet<Park>();
```

This is Park.java

```
 @Entity
@Table(name="parcheggio", catalog="SMARTPARK")
public class Park implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7630704706109692038L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_park", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private  int idPark;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name="nome_park")
    private  String nomePark;

    @Column(name="descrizione")
    private  String descrizione;

    @Column(name="indirizzo")
    private String indirizzo;

    @Column(name="citta")
    private String citta;


    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name="users_parcheggio", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="park_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name="user_id") })

    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "park")
    private List<Piano> piano;

    public Park(){
    }

    public Park(int idPark, String nomePark, String descrizione, String indirizzo, String citta, Set<User> users, List<Piano> piano){
        this.idPark = idPark;
        this.nomePark = nomePark;
        this.descrizione = descrizione;
        this.indirizzo = indirizzo;
        this.citta = citta;
        this.users = users;
        this.piano = piano;
    }

    public List<Piano> getPiano() {
        return piano;
    }

    public void setPiano(List<Piano> piano) {
        this.piano = piano;
    }

    public  int getIdPark() {
        return idPark;
    }

    public  void setIdPark(int idPark) {
        this.idPark = idPark;
    }


    public  String getNomePark() {
        return nomePark;
    }

    public  void setNomePark(String nomePark) {
        this.nomePark = nomePark;
    }


    public  String getDescrizione() {
        return descrizione;
    }

    public  void setDescrizione(String descrizione) {
        this.descrizione = descrizione;
    }

    public String getIndirizzo() {
        return indirizzo;
    }

    public void setIndirizzo(String indirizzo) {
        this.indirizzo = indirizzo;
    }

    public String getCitta() {
        return citta;
    }

    public void setCitta(String citta) {
        this.citta = citta;
    }

    public Set<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + idPark;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Park other = (Park) obj;
        if (idPark != other.idPark)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

and in Piano.java

```
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_park")
    public Park getPark() {
        return park;
    }

    public void setPark(Park park) {
        this.park = park;
    }
```

When I use this 3 classes in couples (User with Park or Park with Piano) everything goes well, but now I have to get all Piano for a given User.

In my PianoDaoImpl I have this method

```
public List<Piano> findPianoByUser() {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String name = auth.getName();
        User user = userService.findBySso(name);
        int userId = user.getId();
        Query q = getSession().createQuery("from Park p join p.users u where u.id = :userId").setParameter("userId", userId);
        List<Park> parks = q.list();

        Query query = getSession().createQuery("from Piano p where p.park in :parks").setParameterList("parks", parks);
        List piani = query.list();

        return piani;
    }
```

The *q* query gives me correctly the parks list for the user. Then I pass this list to the second query and I got this exception

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of it.besmart.models.Park.idPark
```

caused by

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set int field it.besmart.models.Park.idPark to [Ljava.lang.Object;
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'd imagine Park.idPark needs to be of type Integer. It seems that you currently have it set to int, which is a primitive.

Comment: if i put it Integer I got `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Integer field it.besmart.models.Park.idPark to [Ljava.lang.Object;` so the exception comes anyway

Comment: Try to post the Park class

Comment: edited the question with Park.java

Comment: Do you have a defined getter and setter for all of the Park fields?

Comment: Yes i do, there was a typo error before, the problem occurs both if i put idPark as int or as Integer

Comment: Can you try to change your  firsty query to:

`Query q = getSession().createQuery("select p.idPark from Park p join p.users u where u.id = :userId").setParameter("userId", userId);`
        `List<Integer> parkIds = q.list();`


second query to: 

`Query query = getSession().createQuery("from Piano p where p.park.parkId in :parkIds").setParameterList("parkIds", parkIds);`

Comment: it works! The problem was I was retrieving objects from the first query?

Answer (score 2):

The cause of issue, that is `idPark` of the reference type `Integer` can't be assigned with a value of primitive type `int`.
Try to replace this.

```
    @Column(name = "id_park", unique = true, nullable = false)
     private  Integer idPark;
```

With:

```
   @Column(name = "id_park", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private  int idPark;
```

Try to check the value of `userId` have `Integer` not `int`, because I think with this you have the exception:

```
  "from Park p join p.users u where u.id = :userId").setParameter("userId", userId);
```

Comment: i logged `userId` and it returns correctly an int. I think the problem is in the second query, the first one gives me a correct List of Park